# How to do a case insensitive lookup over a set of nodes in XSLT/XPATH?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-3.0, xpath-3.0

Say I have this data:

```xml
<recipe name="Fruit Salad">
  <ingredient name="banana"/>
  <ingredient name="oRange"/>
  <ingredient name="APPLE"/>
</recipes>
```

and I have this other data:

```xml
<refrigerator>
  <item name="appLe"/>
  <item name="Grape"/>
</refrigerator>
```

and I want to find all the things needed for my recipes that are not already in my frig, to make a shopping list. The right answer is the set `{banana, orange}`

This doesn't work because `lower-case()` only takes a string. So does `translate()`:

```xml
<xsl:variable name="missing-ingredients" select="recipe/ingredient/@name[not(lower-case(.)=lower-case(refrigerator/item/@name))]"/>
```

Without resorting to cheating (going outside `xslt` and `xpath`), how can I do this? I find it hard to imagine they didn't make a provision for this inside `xpath`, since node lookups are the bread and butter of `xslt` and `xpath`, and weren't not on the first versions anymore.

If I could just convert a list of nodes (a node-set, I suppose) to lowercase, I would be home free.

Comment: While asking an XSLT question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Input XML.
(2) Your logic, and XSLT that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample XML in the #1 above.
(4) XSLT processor and its conformance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, or 3.0.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky, all 4 elements you listed were in my original question. Which element are you saying is missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a problem with this XPath expression:

```xml
recipe/ingredient/@name[not(lower-case(.)=lower-case(refrigerator/item/@name))]
```

The expresson `refrigerator/item/@name` yields a sequence of attributes, rather than a single string, as the `lower-case()` function expects. You need to lower-case each one of the items in that sequence, by passing them to the `lower-case()` function individually. e.g.

```xml
for 
   $stored-ingredient 
in 
   refrigerator/item/@name 
return 
   lower-case($stored-ingredient)
```

In XPath 3 there's a more concise alternative, the ["simple map" operator](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-30/#id-map-operator) `!`, which would look like this:

```xml
refrigerator/item/@name ! lower-case(.)
```

Comment: I'm in XPath 3. The simple map seems to work. The expression I'm after is inside a `select` attribute of an `xsl:variable`. I'll try the full expression tomorrow. [I'm beat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73875729/1045881).

Comment: [OK here's what I ended up with](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73875729/1045881)

Answer (score 3):

For cross-references, I would use a key e.g.

```
  <xsl:param name="frig" expand-text="no">
    <refrigerator>
      <item name="appLe"/>
      <item name="Grape"/>
    </refrigerator>    
  </xsl:param>
  
  <xsl:key name="frig-item-by-name" match="refrigerator/item" use="lower-case(@name)"/>
```

Then you can select e.g.

```
  <xsl:template match="recipe">
    <section>
      <h1>{local-name()}</h1>
      <section>
        <h2>Available ingredients</h2>
        <xsl:where-populated>
          <ul>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="ingredient[key('frig-item-by-name', lower-case(@name), $frig)]"/>
          </ul>
        </xsl:where-populated>
      </section>
      <section>
        <h2>Ingredients to buy</h2>
        <xsl:where-populated>
          <ul>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="ingredient[not(key('frig-item-by-name', lower-case(@name), $frig))]"/>
          </ul>
        </xsl:where-populated>
      </section>
    </section>
  </xsl:template>
```

Of course, if the data of the frig is in the same document as the primary input, drop the parameter and drop the third argument of the `key` function calls. And of course instead of inlining the data, as I did for self-containedness of the example, if the data is in a second document, use e.g. `<xsl:param name="frig" select="doc('frig-data.xml')"/>`.

Complete sample to put above snippets into context:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    expand-text="yes"
    version="3.0">
  
  <xsl:param name="frig" expand-text="no">
    <refrigerator>
      <item name="appLe"/>
      <item name="Grape"/>
    </refrigerator>    
  </xsl:param>
  
  <xsl:key name="frig-item-by-name" match="refrigerator/item" use="lower-case(@name)"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="recipe">
    <section>
      <h1>{local-name()}</h1>
      <section>
        <h2>Available ingredients</h2>
        <xsl:where-populated>
          <ul>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="ingredient[key('frig-item-by-name', lower-case(@name), $frig)]"/>
          </ul>
        </xsl:where-populated>
      </section>
      <section>
        <h2>Ingredients to buy</h2>
        <xsl:where-populated>
          <ul>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="ingredient[not(key('frig-item-by-name', lower-case(@name), $frig))]"/>
          </ul>
        </xsl:where-populated>
      </section>
    </section>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="ingredient">
    <li>{lower-case(@name)}</li>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" html-version="5"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>.NET XSLT Fiddle Example</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I like this a lot better than my answer. Shame that on previous similar questions this answer wasn't there. Or that I missed it if it was there. Oh well, in any case, now it's here.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my working XPath 2 answer:

```xml
<xsl:variable name="ingredients" select="recipe/ingredients/@name"/>
<xsl:variable name="inventory" select="refrigerator/item/@name"/> 
<xsl:variable name="lower-ingredients">
    <xsl:for-each select="$ingredients">
        <item>
            <xsl:value-of select="lower-case(.)"/>
        </item>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="lower-inventory">
    <xsl:for-each select="$inventory">
        <item>
            <xsl:value-of select="lower-case(.)"/>
        </item>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="missing-ingredients" select="$lower-ingredients/item[not(. = $lower-inventory/item)]"/>
```

And here's what I ended up with in XPath 3:

```xml
<xsl:variable name="lower-ingredients" select="$ingredients ! lower-case(.)"/>
<xsl:variable name="lower-inventory" select="$inventory ! lower-case(.)"/>
<xsl:variable name="on-hand" select="$lower-ingredients[. = $lower-inventory])"/>
<xsl:variable name="missing-ingredients" select="$lower-ingredients[not(. = $lower-inventory)]"/>
```

Comment: In XPath 2 you can just do `<xsl:variable name="lower-ingredients" select="for $ingredient in $ingredients return lower-case($ingredient)"/>`

Comment: @ConalTuohy, thanks. I changed my ? tag to be xpath 3, so fortunately I can use that answer, as it's much more concise.